# Need to draw a map with Multipolygon coordinates using OL3

Tags: postgresql, openlayers

I am getting a response from my DB(postgresql), something like this:

```
["{\"type\":\"MultiPolygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[[155917.153194497,210867.51599128],[155917.193016207,210867.518011615],[155917.232550311,210867.523198616],[155917.271545395,210867.531519298],[155917.309753475,210867.542920746],[155917.346931569,210867.557330454],[155917.382843247,210867.574656784],[155917.417260133,210867.594789552],[155917.449963355,210867.617600725],[155917.459648623,210867.625136389],[155925.049736443,210873.681616414],[155930.5385101,210878.034228535],[155930.557274147,210878.049870081],[155930.57525183,210878.066409438],[155930.592400237,210878.083807125],[155930.608678436,210878.102021616],[155930.62404757,210878.121009431],[155857.717145232,210821.110027787]]]]}"]
```

I need to make a polygon the map using these coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response (in this case) is a single element array containing a json in string format.  The code to use it would look like

```
new ol.Feature({geometry: new ol.geom.MultiPolygon(JSON.parse(response[0]).coordinates)})
```

However you might want to extent your code in case responses contain multiple elements or geometry types

```
for (var i=0; i<reponse.length; i++) {
    var json = JSON.parse(response[i]);
    switch (json.type) {
    case "MultiPolygon":
        ...
        ... new ol.Feature({geometry: new ol.geom.MultiPolygon(json.coordinates)}) ...
        ...
        break;
    case ...
```